# Figure legend doubles Matlab code execution time

Tags: matlab, optimization, matlab-figure

I noticed that if I have Matlab code where my figure has to display a legend, the running time increases significantly.
Here's an example:

```
clear all
close all
clc

% legend test
x = [0:1:100];
y = x.^(3.123);

figure('Name', 'X-Y and X-X plot')
plot(x,y)
hold all
plot(x,x)
legend('1', '232')
```

Gives a running time of 1.1 seconds. Same code without the `legend('1', '232')` line has an execution time of 0.4 seconds. I find it very odd that a simple legend increases the running  time this much.
With the profiler I found that the function mainly responsible for the time increase is called `graphics/private/texmex`. It has a self-time of 0.12 seconds and is called 4 times. When I don't create a legend this function is not called.

Is there a way to speed up my code, while still generating a legend in a figure?

I'm running 64-bit Matlab 2012b on Mac OS 10.8.3.

When I run the code in the example with `set(0, DefaultTextInterpreter, 'none')` the `texmex` function is called by `tex>localCallTeXParser`, which is called by `scribe.legend.methods>strsize`, etc...:

```
graphics/private/texmex
tex>localCallTeXParser
scribe.legend.methods>strsize
scribe.legend.methods>getsizeinfo
scribe.legend.methods>getsize
scribe.legend.methods
scribe.legend.legend
```

Comment: 0.4 seconds is relatively not much when plotting figures. Why do you care about performance when you're creating plots?

Comment: This is just an example, I have a code that outputs multiple plots and it's annoying to wait for it. I found it odd that adding a legend increases the time this much. The plotting itself, and even the code to make a hardcopy of the figure is not slow, it's only the legend that slows it down.

Comment: Can you describe how you generate the plots, _e.g_ in a for loop, using `hold on`, etc...? That would help giving a more specific answer.

Comment: I do it as shown in the example. I create a figure, plot data, `hold all` and plot data  again. Then I create a legend. I do this 7 times in my code, by copy pasting the figure creation/plot code 7 times.

Comment: Huh, I guess they changed the `scribe.legend.methods>strsize` function between `2012a` and `2012b`, because my version of this method does not include a call to `tex>localCallTeXParser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with a project of my own.  I wanted to dynamically update some line plots quickly using a slider, but noticed that the having a legend active really killed the performance I was getting.

I found the solution to my problem here - http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-performance/.

From the second listed performance hack, I added the lines

<strike>set(gca,'LegendColorbarListeners',[]);</strike>

```
setappdata(gca,'LegendColorbarManualSpace',1);
setappdata(gca,'LegendColorbarReclaimSpace',1);
```

to my code.  I got an error message for the first line of code that was mentioned, so I struck it out above.  Regardless though, the other two lines of code made my plots update just as quickly with a legend as they did without the legend being present.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `legend` is using a TeX interpreter (at least, that's what `texmex` sounds like). In that case, you could try

```
legend({'1', '232'}, 'Interpreter', 'none');
```

This will disable the TeX interpreter and therefore may improve the performance. I should probably note that I've never experienced any trouble with the speed of the `legend` function, so it's probably something specific to your plots and/or MATLAB installation/version.

**Edit**: I have the feeling that the above will draw the legend with the TeX interpreter first, then disable it and draw it again. Try doing the following before drawing the legend or perhaps before drawing the figure (not sure at which point MATLAB will promote the default properties to an actual figure / axes / legend):

```
set(0, 'DefaultTextInterpreter', 'none');
```

Comment: I've set the interpreter to none, but the `legend` still calls `graphics/private/texmex` and the problem remains.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've tried the `DefaultTextInterpreter` but the `texmex` function is still called.

Comment: I've run your example in the profiler and can't find where it calls `texmex` at all; in fact I don't even think `texmex` exists on my system - what version of MATLAB is it? What file calls `texmex`, and what is the stack at that point? Also, on my system it takes about 0.2 seconds to run.